# linking css file to base html docuemnt - django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a django project and i have been trying to link a css file to the base.html document to begin implimenting some css to my file. I have bootstrap linked already but i want to add more customization... Here is what i have so far..

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid blue5">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the css file

```
.blue5 {
  background-color: lightblue,
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can link a CSS and HTML file like this:

In your HTML code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
      <link href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


      <link href="pathToYourCSSfile" rel="stylesheet"> 


      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid blue5">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your css file only contains these two lines it will be better to include them in the head of the document

```
<head>
    ...
    <script ...>
    <style>
         .blue5 {
             background-color: lightblue,
         }
    </style>
</head>
```

otherwise just like the others css, add a new link tag:

```
<link href="{% static 'path to your file.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: the question is... is my path for the css file that i already have the correct path because the css is not applying to the page...

Comment: okay! if "blog.css" already works, why don't you put your file in the same folder as blog.css ?

Comment: and then <link href="{% static 'css/yourfile.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: the thing is what i have right now is not working. I just want to know that if the path i have is incorrect or if i need to create a different path... I have the blog.css file in the css file under static but nothing i put in it applied to the file.. i just want to know if the path is the problem or what the problem is...

Comment: hmmm okay ! have you tried to put some css from your file in blog.css and check if you see the changes! if nothing happens this should be  a problem with your css properties. So you have to post more informations

Comment: it's a bit difficult! I have to see the html and the css file :-/ do have a fiddle for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153409/discussion-between-omar-jandali-and-marouen-mhiri).